# SQL join column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a set of table as following

```
customer(cus_id,cus_first_name,cus_last_name);
insert into customer values ('c001', 'tan', 'wah khang');
```

I want to create a select statement to display the first name join with the last name.
Example :

```
tan wah khang
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the (this is not called "join" but) **concatenation** **[`|| (double pipe)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm)** operator:

```
SELECT (cus_first_name || ' ' || cus_last_name) AS full_name
FROM customer
```

Comment: Out of interest, what's the benefit of using this syntax over something like `concat_ws()`?

Comment: @BenSwinburne: Is `CONCAT_WS` an Oracle function? I thought it was a MySQL one.

Answer (score 2):

`||` isn't quite equivalent to MySQL's `CONCAT_WS`. `CONCAT_WS` eliminates the delimiter if one of the operands is `NULL`. So if firstname is `NULL` and lastname is 'Smith', in MySQL:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', firstname, lastname) returns "Smith"
```

whereas, in Oracle:

```
firstname || ' ' || lastname returns " Smith" (prepended with a space)
```

I'd love to know if there's a true equivalent, or if you'd have to write a stored procedure to emulate `CONCAT_WS`. It's terribly useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
select cus_first_name || ' ' || cus_last_name from customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
select cus_first || ' ' || cus_last from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, Informix:

```
select cus_first_name || ' ' || cus_last_name from customer
```

In SQL-Server:

```
select cus_first_name + ' ' + cus_last_name from customer
```

In MS-Access:

```
select cus_first_name & ' ' & cus_last_name from customer
```

In MySQL:

```
select concat(cus_first_name , ' ', cus_last_name) from customer
```

In Informix:

```
select concatenate(cus_first_name,concatenate(' ',cus_last_name)) from customer
```